Repeating sequences in zero-player game similar to Conway's Game of Life
Is there an efficient way to find a repeating sequence in this zero-player game?
The only approach have had any success with is by brute force, changing the percentages of the rate at which a Demon, a Soldier, or an empty cell is placed. Considering that there are $3^{100}$ initial states is it possible to play every initial state to count the number of repeating sequences?

Hello! $3^{100}$ is large enough that to check each one, you would need to have a very advanced computer to check all of them. To find one, I'd suggest checking many small, basic configurations. (Think about how small or simple the common repeating sequences in the Game of Life are.) Unfortunately, that game will be much harder to find repeating patterns than the game of life because of directional preference and the multing. This game resembles population dynamics, which is chaotic and starting configurations with slight differences might have very different outcomes that are very different.

You might play it on a smaller field first. Say 5x5 instead of 10x10. $3^{25}$ is a much easier goal to reach, and the information you gain may prove useful in the larger field. Also note that the three cycles of 8,5,3 are pairwise relatively prime, so would require having the same pattern 120 turns later to be sure you have a true interstice (the site sometimes declares them, but if you go on a few more rounds, they break because the demons/soldiers were not at the same places in their life-cycles).
